# Chukim list with sources

Tags: torah-study, mitzvah

My search is for a list of [chukim](http://www.torah.org/learning/olas-shabbos/5763/chukas.html).
Since I don't like 'reinventing the wheel', I was wondering if there is one already available from some reference work.

Comment: TzGaBeR, welcome to Mi Yodeya! I hope you enjoy the site. If you haven't, please take the site [tour].

Comment: Are you specifically looking for an exhaustive list?

Comment: Here's a pretty exhaustive list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/613_commandments#Maimonides.27_list

Comment: I'm looking for a list of mitzvot which most authorities agree is a hok. Wikipedia doesn't say which is a hok or not.